# How can I click on a row in one sheet, and goto another sheet?

Tags: tableau-desktop

I have a Tableau Desktop report with 2 data sources and 2 sheets.

Each data source uses a SQL Server stored procedure.

I had to break it up into 2, because when combining all the data for all the drivers, it took way too long to load.

So the first sheet just loads a summary for each driver like this:

```
driverID    lastName
---------------------
348743      James          <--- *CLICK* I'm trying to figure out how to click a row, to goto the 2nd sheet
349368      Roduh
846331      Cortez
984631      Rockwell
```

The 2nd one, loads specifics for one driver(I currently have `driverID` **348743** hard-coded):

```
driverID        Event               DateTime
--------------------------------------------
348743          Lunch break         3/1/2023 11:45AM  
348743          Flat tire fix       3/1/2023 03:10PM 
348743          Dinner break        3/1/2023 06:25PM
348743          Night rest          3/1/2023 10:30PM  
348743          Breakfast break     3/2/2023 07:45AM
```

I made an action on sheet1, so when I click on it, it goes to sheet2.  But that's as far as I am able to get.

Is there a way, so that if I click on a sheet1 row, it takes that `driverID` and goes to sheet2 and shows the data specific
to that driver?

I haven't been able to figure this out....

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I recommend making one tableau data source that has 2 database tables, with a one to many relationship defined between them. Say relating a Driver table to an Event table. Only use a stored procedure or custom sql if absolutely necessary- usually it’s not needed and better to point to tables or views

Second, there are multiple ways you can allow users to navigate between summary and detailed views. The Simplest is to put both views on a dashboard; create a filter action from the dashboard menu where selecting an item in the summary view filters the detail view. Be sure to define the action to show nothing when  nothing is selected (to avoid fetching the world at start)

So read about filter actions. You might want to check out viz in a tooltip as a similar approach. Or read about guided analytics with tableau.

As a helpful touch, also edit the title of the detailed view, and use the insert button on the title dialog to show the name(s) of who is being filtered to

Comment: Hi Alex, so I tried this and the query takes FOREVER to execute..because the event table is absolutly so big!  The system logs like every second and it's just a ton of rows for each driver....and with over 1.5 million driver entries, it is just too much.  This is why I wanted 2 data sources...one with all the drivers  for the first sheet. Then the 2nd sheet would only contain data for one driver(the one who the user clicked on)...

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell - is your data in a text file or a database? Sounds like it is one long table instead of factored into multiple tables right? If you are starting with one long text file, then you could benefit from using Tableau Prep Builder to create a pre-aggregated file summarizing each user which you can then use together with your original as described in my response

Comment: It's in a database... the driver table isn't that big, but the driver entries table is enormous.

Comment: ok then, what does your Data Source look like in Tableau? click on the word Data Source at the bottom left. Do you have two tables shown on the main canvas? or one? And why are you using stored procedures? I'd try connecting to the database, putting the driver table out, then adding the driver entries table, to get two related tables. Define the 1-M relationship with keys, Then make a worksheet just showing info from the driver table. That should be fast. Then another (with a filter) showing info from the driver entries table. Then connecting them with an action, and likely adding an extract.

Comment: So the 2nd data source, that uses driver entries...how do I limit it from pulling in all entries for all drivers?   That's where the performance issue comes up....